# Getting invalid identifier error in oracle sql for my foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been attempting to create a table and I keep getting met with the invalid identifier error. I have looked at threads on this website but those fixes don't really help me.

My code:

```
DROP TABLE ClassEnrollments;
DROP TABLE Engineers;
DROP TABLE Faculty;
DROP TABLE Classes;

CREATE TABLE Engineers 
(
    EID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( EID ),
    Lastname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Firstname varchar(30),
    Email varchar(50),
    Graddate date 
);

CREATE TABLE Faculty 
(
    FID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( FID ),
    Lastname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Firstname varchar(30),
    Email varchar(50),
    Hiredate date 
);

CREATE TABLE Classes 
(
    CID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( CID ),
    Subject varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Catalognbr int,
    Title varchar(30) 
);

CREATE TABLE ClassEnrollments 
(
    EnID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EnID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES Classes (CID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FID) REFERENCES Faculty (FID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EID) REFERENCES Engineers (EID) 
);
```

This is the error I get :

> Error starting at line : 29 in command -
> CREATE TABLE ClassEnrollments (
> EnID int NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY ( EnID ),
> FOREIGN KEY ( CID ) REFERENCES Classes( CID ),
> FOREIGN KEY  ( FID ) REFERENCES Faculty( FID ),
> FOREIGN KEY  ( EID ) REFERENCES Engineers( EID ) )
>
> Error report -
> ORA-00904: "CID": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Comment: Your table `ClassEnrollments` doesn't have a column `CID` defined - thus you cannot make it a foreign key (since it doesn't exist......) The `FOREIGN KEY` constraints **doesn't** define a column in your table - that column **must exist** so that you can make it a foreign key

Comment: The should be `cid references classes (cid)`, etc.

Comment: Also, it's `varchar2` not `varchar`.